# solspace super search 'super_search_keywords' and 'csrf_token' tags not parsed

Tags: solspace, csrf

EE 2.7.2
MSM

I've just installed SOlspace Super Search and added the simple form example from teh docs but neither the {super_search_keywords} or {csrf_token} tags are getting parsed, both are rendered literally.

```
        <form method="post" action="{path='search/results'}" role="form">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{csrf_token}" />
        <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="{super_search_keywords}" placeholder="Find a resource" />
        <button type="submit" name="commit" value="draft"></button>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </form>
```

I can't see any config that I've missed, is there something else that needs to be included on the form page?

Comment: What version of Super Search are you using? Please provide the exact version number. Also, do you see an unparsed `{super_search_keywords}` variable, or an empty value? Are you logged in as a Super Admin when you see this?

Comment: 2.2.3, it displays '{super_search_keywords}', and yes I am logged in as Super Admin

Comment: It also displays '{super_search_keywords}' to non-logged in users.

Comment: Do you have a Super Search tag anywhere on the template? Eg. {exp:super_search:results} or {exp:super_search:search}. The tag pair can contain nothing, could just need to be present to parse other variables on the page.

Comment: An empty Super Search tag doesn't work, but the super_search_keywords tag gets replaced with the last search term if I surround the form with '{exp:super_search:search}', is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: After adding '{exp:super_search:search}' tags to the page, the '{exp:super_search:search}' tag does get replaced with the last search term that I used, but ALL visitors to the site see my last search term!

Answer (score 1):

`csrf_token` has been introduced in EE 2.8+. See http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/search/#csrf_token

EE 2.7.x used `XID` before it was renamed to `csrf_token`. Therefore, you need to add an XID hash instead if you're on EE 2.7.x:

```
<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}" />
```

Comment: I still need a fix for {super_search_keywords} not being parsed though